# What is the right way to use ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, async-await

Wondering what is the correct way to use ConfigureAwait(false) between the following 2 ways:

```
var taskOne = _service.MethodOneAsync();
var taskTwo = _service.MethodTwoAsync();
var responseFromOne = await taskOne.ConfigureAwait(false);
var responseFromTwo = await taskTwo.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

```
var taskOne = _service.MethodOneAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var taskTwo = _service.MethodTwoAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var responseFromOne = await taskOne;
var responseFromTwo = await taskTwo;
```

Also, what is the difference in the usage between the 2 approaches.

Comment: I feel like this question is similar to asking: "what's the difference between `var value = 1 + 1; var result = value;` and `var value= 1; var result = value + 1;`?" The question is: do you need `ConfigureAwait(false)` here? If so, why?

Comment: I do need to use the ConfigureAwait(false) because I do not care if the the original context is maintained in further code execution or not.

Comment: My question is exactly that, if there is any difference between the two approaches? I get from your comment is that, there isn't.

Comment: In both cases you're calling `.ConfigureAwait` before the `await` happens, and in both cases you get a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` which you ultimately call `await` on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @Llama said, there are very little difference between the two.

`ConfigureAwait` is simply setting which gives you a ConfiguredTaskAwaitable, which will run before the `await` statement no matter which way you go.

---

As for why you would use `ConfigureAwait` that is a diferrent issue. Traditionally this method was mainly used, (but not limited to), preventing **deadlocks** in your code and databases. So if you do have locks in your code, or you are referencing a database then it is a good idea to used it.

Note on Databases

These days if you are making a EF connection to an SQL db you really don't to use `ConfigureAwait`. For these it has become much more safe and it is at the point where even large industries will leave it out.

However, when making ODBC calls or connecting to other type of databases it is still important.

There is a great article on it's usage here: [Click Me](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f)

Comment: Here is the [article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) by Stephen Cleary. He states that, "A good rule of thumb is to use ConfigureAwait(false) unless you know you do need the context."

In my case, I do not need the same context. Hence, I am using the ConfigureAwait. 

Also, my question was more of about 'does the execution differ in any way.'

Answer (score 3):

From the people that built and maintain the feature: [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring whether the `taskOne` and `taskTwo` variables have meaningful names in the second version, both versions are functionally equivalent. Also both versions are flawed, both for the same reason, but only the first can be fixed. The problem is that in case the `taskOne` fails, the `taskTwo` will be leaked as a fire-and-forget task. Letting tasks run in the background unobserved, with your application having lost track of them, is not a good idea, especially if these tasks modify the state of the application while they are running. To fix this problem you must `await` **both** tasks to complete, not each one individually:

```
var taskOne = _service.MethodOneAsync();
var taskTwo = _service.MethodTwoAsync();
await Task.WhenAll(taskOne, taskTwo).ConfigureAwait(false);
// At this point both tasks are completed
var resultOne = await taskOne;
var resultTwo = await taskTwo;
```

Obviously this fix cannot be applied in the second version, because there is no [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall)-equivalent available for [`ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.configuredtaskawaitable) structs.

> This type is intended for compiler use; do not use it directly in your code.